# iphone problem adding splashscreen

Tags: iphone, splash-screen

i've a little problem, i've add a default.png in my app and it work.
I've modify my file, delete file and reference and upload my new file.
On my iphone the image does not appear, only some second of blackscreen and after my app start. In the simulator the splashscreen appear.
I've try to delete my app on iphone, make a clean all and rebuild & install but nothing...
I've try to make clean all, close xcode, delete default.png to my project directory (sometimes exist, sometimes no), open xcode, add my file and build & install on my iphone but nothing...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

partially resolved, i've delete my file and reference, check if it's delete in my project directory, readd file BUT in other directory and it works, i think there will be some reference to my splashscreen that i cannot found.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Default.png file capitalized? The iPhone uses a case-sensitive filesystem. Not sure if that would cause the problems you're having, but it's worth checking on.

Comment: i've try with both D & d but is the same. i'm searching some hidden reverence to *efault.png